# Replace null values in query with a previous value

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm creating a query through SSMS, working on SQL Server 2012.

Part of my query is to find the supervisor for the associates.  My issue is that for the table containing supervisor names it doesn't make a new daily record.  Because there is no record for that day my query shows up as NULL for supervisor.

How can I fill these NULL values with the last Supervisor they reported to in the table?

Supervisor Table

```
MeasureDate    Associate            Supervisor
2019-09-02     Goodman, Michelle    Moody, Robin
2019-09-01     Goodman, Michelle    Moody, Robin
2019-08-20     Goodman, Michelle    Henry, Jack
2019-08-19     Goodman, Michelle    Henry, Jack
```

Current Query Output

```
Date        Supervisor     Associate
2019-09-01  Moody, Robin   Goodman, Michelle
2019-08-21  NULL           Goodman, Michelle
2019-08-20  Henry, Jack    Goodman, Michelle
```

Improved Query Output

```
Date        Supervisor     Associate
2019-09-01  Moody, Robin   Goodman, Michelle
2019-08-21  Henry, Jack    Goodman, Michelle
2019-08-20  Henry, Jack    Goodman, Michelle
```

Current Query

```
SELECT 
z.Date,
z.Supervisor,
z.Associate,
CAST('XXX' AS char) AS [Group],
z.Task,
Sum(z.Minutes) as Minutes,
Sum(z.Count) as Cases

FROM
(
SELECT
a.DS_LOAD_DT AS Date,
c.CASE_TASK_TYPE_NM AS Task,
b.AssociateName AS Associate,
d.Supervisor,
(CONVERT(decimal,a.DURATIONSEC)/60) AS Minutes,
COUNT(*) AS Count

FROM DW_RawData_XXXDetail a
LEFT JOIN DW_Dim_AssociateMapping b ON a.XXX_EMP_ID = b.XXX_ID AND a.DS_LOAD_DT = b.ScheduleDate
LEFT JOIN DW_Dim_XXX_Case_Types c ON left(a.MSG_TYPE_CD, patindex('%[0-9][^0-9]%', a.MSG_TYPE_CD)) = 
c.CASE_TASK_TYPE_ID
LEFT JOIN OperationScoreCard_Daily_Associates d ON b.AssociateName = d.Associate AND b.ScheduleDate = 
d.MeasureDate

WHERE b.MUID = '400'
AND a.DS_LOAD_DT >= '2019-08-01'

GROUP BY
a.DS_LOAD_DT,
c.CASE_TASK_TYPE_NM,
b.AssociateName,
d.Supervisor,
(CONVERT(decimal,a.DURATIONSEC)/60)
) z

GROUP BY
z.Date,
z.Task,
z.Associate,
z.Supervisor
```

Comment: Apologies for the aliases, it's how we use them internally so it's normal for our group.  My output has decimal places, why do you believe that it would become a whole number?

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 '2019-08-01' as Date, Supervisor, Associate
from DW_RawData_XXXDetail --plus any joins you need
where Date <= '2019-08-01'
group by MAX(Date), Supervisor, Associate
```

The group by gives you the most recent date for each Supervisor/Associate combo, so you can just compare that to whatever target date you need. Ideally replace the hardcoded date with a variable.

Comment: It is difficult for anyone without experience to see what you are suggesting. Using a literal and giving it the alias "Date" while referring to it in other places in the query is beyond confusing. And you won't be able to group by an aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lag function to get previous value of supervisor by using partitioning over associate. 
For more info refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Below is an example:

```
    CREATE TABLE LogicalConnection (
  `cpId` VARCHAR(11),
  `sequenceNumber` VARCHAR(11)
);

INSERT INTO LogicalConnection
  (`cpId`, `sequenceNumber`)
VALUES
  ('1', '10'),
  ('1', NULL),
  ('2', '20');

    SELECT t.cpId, 
    case when t.sequenceNumber is null then lag(t.sequenceNumber) over (partition by t.cpId) else t.sequenceNumber end
from LogicalConnection t
```